# How would I populate my HTML table on my page using PHP without breaking my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, html-table

I am trying to make a simple dashboard using HTML, CSS, JS, and PHP.

I have some JavaScript on my page handling most of the transitions and moving the DIVs around. My home page also has an HTML table that will be pulling some rows from a DB, but when I use PHP to connect to the SQL Server and return the rows, my JavaScript stops working. Specifically, when I convert my page from an .html extension to a .php extension the JavaScript no longer runs and I get errors in the console. What would be the best way to pull data from the database to alleviate this issue. Sample Code Below:

The JS has nothing to do with my table, but it stops functioning whenever I start to use php on this page. The JS is used to switch out the divs that are currently showing to simulate switching pages.

HTML - This is my table element that I'm trying to fill from a SQL DB

```
  <body>
    <div class="demo-layout mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-drawer mdl-layout--fixed-header">
      <header class="demo-header mdl-layout__header mdl-color--white mdl-color-text--grey-600">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
          <span><img src=".\images\comp_now.png" width="50%" height="50%"></span>
          <span class="mdl-layout-title">Dashboard</span>
          <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable">
            <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" for="search">
              <i class="material-icons">search</i>
            </label>
            <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
              <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="search">
              <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="search">Enter your query...</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
      <!--Side Panel-->
      <div class="demo-drawer mdl-layout__drawer mdl-color--black mdl-color-text--blue-grey-50">
        <header class="demo-drawer-header">
          <img src="images/user.jpg" class="demo-avatar">
          <div class="demo-avatar-dropdown">
            <span>hello@example.com</span>
            <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
            <button id="accbtn" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--icon">
              <i class="material-icons" role="presentation">arrow_drop_down</i>
              <span class="visuallyhidden">Accounts</span>
            </button>
            <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="accbtn">
              <li class="mdl-menu__item">
                <!-- Accent-colored raised button with ripple -->
                <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">
                  Sign Out
                </button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </header>
        <!--Page Navigation-->
        <nav class="demo-navigation mdl-navigation mdl-color--white mdl-color-text--blue-grey-50">
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" onclick="switchMain('PO_LIST')"><i class="mdl-color-text--blue-A400 material-icons" role="presentation">list</i>PO List</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" onclick="switchMain('PO_ITEMS')"><i class="mdl-color-text--blue-A400 material-icons" role="presentation">shopping_cart</i>PO Items</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" onclick="switchMain('VENDORS')"><i class="mdl-color-text--blue-A400 material-icons" role="presentation">storefront</i>Vendors</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" onclick="switchMain('REPORTS')"><i class="mdl-color-text--blue-A400 material-icons" role="presentation">bar_chart</i>Reports</a>
          <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <main class="mdl-layout__content mdl-color--grey-100" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 20px;">
      <div class="main" id="PO_LIST">
        <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
          <!-- Accent-colored raised button with ripple -->
          <button id="New_PO" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent trigger" style="margin-right: 20px;"><i class="mdl-color-text--white material-icons">add</i>
            New Purchase Order
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table" style="overflow-y: auto">
            <thead class="mdl-color--amber-700">
              <tr>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Edit</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Status</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">PO Number</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">PO Date</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Name</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Vendor</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Received</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Shipping Cost</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Taxes</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">PO Total</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Requestor</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Budget</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <?php 
                  include 'po_list_table.php'; 
                  pullDBRows();
                ?>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main" id="PO_ITEMS" style="display: none; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto;">
        <div style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
          <!-- Accent-colored raised button with ripple -->
          <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent new_item_trigger" style="margin-right: 20px;"><i class="mdl-color-text--white material-icons">add</i>
            New Item
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table">
            <thead class="mdl-color--amber-700">
              <tr>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Edit</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Item ID</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Name</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Description</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Brand</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Vendor</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Quantity</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Unit Price</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Line Price</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Category</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><i class="mdl-color-text--black material-icons">edit</i></td>
                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">POI-000001</td>
                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Keyboard & Mouse Combo</td>
                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Logitech MK545</td>
                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Logitech</td>
                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Best Buy</td>
                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">20</td>
                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">$29.99</td>
                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">$599.80</td>
                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Peripherals</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main" id="VENDORS" style="display: none; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto;">
        <div style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
          <!-- Accent-colored raised button with ripple -->
          <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent trigger3" style="margin-right: 20px;"><i class="mdl-color-text--white material-icons">add</i>
            New Vendor
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table">
            <thead class="mdl-color--amber-700">
              <tr>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Edit</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Vendor ID</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Name</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Description</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Street Address 1</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Street Address 2</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">City</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">State</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Zip</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><i class="mdl-color-text--black material-icons">edit</i></td>
                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">VEN-000001</td>
                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Softchoice</td>
                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Computer Company</td>
                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"></td>
                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"></td>
                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"></td>
                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"></td>
                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main" id="REPORTS" style="display: none; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto;">
        <div style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
          <!-- Accent-colored raised button with ripple -->
          <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" style="margin-right: 20px;"><i class="mdl-color-text--white material-icons">bar_chart</i>
            PO Totals
          </button>
          <!-- Accent-colored raised button with ripple -->
          <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" style="margin-right: 20px;"><i class="mdl-color-text--white material-icons">bar_chart</i>
            Total by Vendor
          </button>
          <!-- Accent-colored raised button with ripple -->
          <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" style="margin-right: 20px;"><i class="mdl-color-text--white material-icons">bar_chart</i>
            Total by Category
          </button>
          <!-- Accent-colored raised button with ripple -->
          <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" style="margin-right: 20px;"><i class="mdl-color-text--white material-icons">bar_chart</i>
            Total by Budget
          </button>
          <!-- Accent-colored raised button with ripple -->
          <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" style="margin-right: 20px;"><i class="mdl-color-text--white material-icons">bar_chart</i>
            2020 PO Total
          </button>
          <!-- Accent-colored raised button with ripple -->
          <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" style="margin-right: 20px;"><i class="mdl-color-text--white material-icons">bar_chart</i>
            2021 PO Total
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <iframe width="100%" height="750px" src="https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=9dec551d-7f49-4b7b-9504-72318e287b04&autoAuth=true&ctid=4c52dc5e-4ed5-4645-a209-ed3c32f5ec3c&config=eyJjbHVzdGVyVXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93YWJpLXVzLWVhc3QyLXJlZGlyZWN0LmFuYWx5c2lzLndpbmRvd3MubmV0LyJ9" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--New Purchase Order Modal-->
      <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
            <h5>New Purchase Order</h5><br>
            <div style="display: inline-block;">
              <form action="#">
                <div class="mdl-grid">
                  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
                    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="PO_Title">
                    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="PO_Title">PO Name</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-grid">
                  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
                    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onfocusout="(this.type='text')" id="PO_Date">
                    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="PO_Date">PO Date</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
                    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onfocusout="(this.type='text')" id="Order_Date">
                    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="Order_Date">Order Date</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-grid">
                  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
                    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" rows= "3" id="Description">
                    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="Description">Description</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-grid">
                  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
                    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onfocusout="(this.type='text')" id="Ship_Date">
                    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="Order_Date">Ship Date</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
                    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onfocusout="(this.type='text')" id="Date_Received">
                    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="Date_Received">Date Received</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-grid">
                  <h6 class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">Shipping Cost: $79.99</h6>
                  <h6 class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">Taxes: $247.89</h6>
                  <h5 class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">PO Total: $25,487.99</h5>
                  <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" style="float: right; margin-left: 80%;">
                    Save Order
                  </button>
              </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-grid" style="float: right;">
              <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
                <h6 style="display: inline-block;">PO Items</h6>
                <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" style="float: right;"><i class="mdl-color-text--white material-icons">add</i>
                  New PO Item
                </button>
                <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" style="float: right; margin-right: 5%;"><i class="mdl-color-text--white material-icons">add</i>
                  From Inventory
                </button>
                <div style= "overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto;">
                  <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table">
                    <thead class="mdl-color--amber-700">
                      <tr>
                        <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Name</th>
                        <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Quantity</th>
                        <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Unit Price</th>
                        <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Line Price</th>
                        <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Category</th>
                        <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-color-text--white">Remove</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Keyboard & Mouse Combo</td>
                        <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">20</td>
                        <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">$29.99</td>
                        <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">$599.80</td>
                        <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Peripherals</td>
                        <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><i class="mdl-color-text--gray material-icons">delete</i></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--New PO Item Modal-->
      <div class="modal2">
          <div class="modal-content2">
            <span class="close-button2">&times;</span>
            <h5>New Inventory Item</h5>
            <form action="#">
              <div class="mdl-grid">
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
                  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="inv_item_name">
                  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="inv_item_name">Item Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
                  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="inv_brand">
                  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="inv_brand">Manufacturer</label>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
                  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="inv_category">
                  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="inv_category">Category</label>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
                  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="inv_vendor">
                  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="inv_vendor">Vendor</label>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
                  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" pattern="-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?" id="inv_quantity">
                  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="inv_quantity">Quantity</label>
                  <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Input is not a number!</span>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
                  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="inv_unit_price">
                  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="inv_unit_price">Unit Price</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="mdl-grid">
                <!-- Accent-colored raised button with ripple -->
                <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" style="margin-left: 65%;">
                  Save Item
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
      </div>
      <!--New Vendor Modal-->
      <div class="modal3">
        <div class="modal-content3">
            <span class="close-button3">&times;</span>
            <h5>New Vendor</h5>
            <form action="#">
              <div class="mdl-grid">
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
                  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="ven_name">
                  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="ven_name">Vendor Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
                  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="ven_addr1">
                  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="ven_addr2">Street Address 1</label>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
                  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="ven_addr2">
                  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="ven_addr2">Street Address 2</label>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
                  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="ven_city">
                  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="ven_city">City</label>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
                  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="ven_state">
                  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="ven_state">State</label>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
                  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" pattern="-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?" id="ven_zip">
                  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="ven-zip">Zip</label>
                  <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Input is not a number!</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="mdl-grid">
                <!-- Accent-colored raised button with ripple -->
                <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" style="margin-left: 65%;">
                  Save Vendor
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
    <!--New Purchase Order JS-->
    <script>
      var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
      var trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");
      var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

      function toggleModal() {
          modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
      }

      function windowOnClick(event) {
          if (event.target === modal) {
              toggleModal();
          }
      }

      trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
      closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
      //window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
    </script>
    <!--New Inventory Item JS-->
    <script>
      var modal2 = document.querySelector(".modal2");
      var trigger2 = document.querySelector(".new_item_trigger");
      var closeButton2 = document.querySelector(".close-button2");

      function toggleModal() {
          modal2.classList.toggle("show-modal2");
      }

      function windowOnClick(event) {
          if (event.target === modal2) {
              toggleModal();
          }
      }

      trigger2.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
      closeButton2.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
      //window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
    </script>
    <!--New Vendor JS-->
    <script>
      var modal3 = document.querySelector(".modal3");
      var trigger3 = document.querySelector(".trigger3");
      var closeButton3 = document.querySelector(".close-button3");

      function toggleModal() {
          modal3.classList.toggle("show-modal3");
      }

      function windowOnClick(event) {
          if (event.target === modal3) {
              toggleModal();
          }
      }

      trigger3.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
      closeButton3.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
      //window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
    </script>
</html>
```

PHP - This is what I'm using to pull the data from the SQL Server

```
<?php
    function pullDBRows(){
        $serverName = "*****";

        $connectionInfo = array ("Database"=>"*****", "UID"=>"*****", "PWD"=>"*****");
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
    
        if( $conn ) {
            "Connection established.<br />";
        } else{
            "Connection could not be established.<br />";
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
    
        $tquery = "Select * from Purchase_Orders";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tquery );
        if( $stmt === false) {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
        }
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<td><i class='mdl-color-text--black material-icons'>edit</i></td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Status']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['PO_Number']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['PO_Date']->format('m/d/y')."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Title']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Vendor']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Date_Received']->format('m/d/y')."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Shipping_Price']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Sales_Tax']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Total_Amount']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Requester']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Budget']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        } 
    }
?>
```

JavaScript - I am using this javascript to switch between "pages" of my site without having to reload the entire page

```
function switchMain(screen) {
    document.getElementById('PO_LIST').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('PO_ITEMS').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('VENDORS').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('REPORTS').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(screen).style.display = 'block';
  }
```

This the error I get in my console: I get it when I click on my page navigation links which are managed by the JavaScript.
[image: Console Error]

Comment: Just changing the file extension shouldn't cause JS errors. Are you sure that's all you changed? What specific errors do you get? The JS you've shown doesn't appear to have anything to do with your table either

Comment: You haven't shown us any of the HTML elements your JS is manipulating (for example, where's "PO_LIST"?).  And you're aware that PHP is 100% "server side", and JS is 100% "browser side": there's never any direct "conflict".  ALSO: the correct filename for a PHP file should be ".php".  Having said that - the PHP rendered as HTML to the browser should behave *identically* to an equivalent static .html page.  FINALLY: please update your post and copy/paste the "errors in the console"

Comment: " I get errors in the console." - Please share!

Comment: Sorry guys, I updated my post to include more information. I'd be happy to provide any more information if needed.

Comment: Thanks. Assuming `document.getElementById('PO_ITEMS').style.display` is line 3 then it means you don't have any element in the page with the ID `PO_ITEMS`. You haven't shown one in your question but then I'm pretty sure you haven't shown us the whole HTML. Anyway this is a pretty basic error and it's hard to see how it could be caused by changing a file extension. The element simply doesn't exist in the HTML at the moment that the JavaScript is executed

Comment: I can provide the entire HTML document, but its ~600 lines, so I didn't know if that was allowed. I can include it if it will help. The element 'PO_Items' exists and everything works fine until I start to integrate my PHP into the document. I will include the entire HTML document.

Comment: This won't solve the problem, but I'd refactor your code a little. Inline javascript should be avoided, assign event listeners instead. Use your links properly to link internally, then use javascript to toggle  a class instead, let css handle hiding or showing. See: https://jsfiddle.net/2L6bum87/

Comment: Thanks for the update. I cant reproduce your error based on the code you've shown, sorry. There must be something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Found that the issue was with my PHP. The datetime formatting I was pulling from my DB was causing issues with loading the PHP correctly.

Comment: Specific details on what to avoid or what exactly was the issue would make your answer a lot more useful to others in future